# Nested fragments and back button cause duplicate id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which hosts 3 fragments in a ViewFlipper. Each of those three fragments hosts fragments of their own. I am using the ViewFlipper like a tab control, which allows me to very simply switch between various "views" in the app. This all works fine, so far.

When the user is inside a view, there is a navigation flow. I use:

```
final FragmentTransaction txn = getChildFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
txn.replace(R.id.view1_silo_container,
                                new View1Fragment());
txn.addToBackStack(null);
txn.commit();
```

to move around inside this view. So as the user navigates, I call some variation of the code above to replace the current fragment with a new one. Again, this all works fine so far.

The problem is that, when I get to the bottom fragment (A>B>C) and then I hit the back button to go from (C>B) I get a duplicate id error. The problem is that the "B" fragment itself has a fragment nested in it. As long as I avoid giving this fragment an id, there is no problem. However, if I give this fragment an id then I get "Duplicate id, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment".

I don't understand why this is a problem, and I haven't found a way to work around it. Am I doing it completely wrong? Is there some small piece I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

This can be found in the [Android 4.2 APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) documentation about the new nested fragments feature.

Once I removed the <fragment> from the layout and used getChildFragmentManager() to insert the fragment 'manually' in onCreateView, it worked fine. No more duplicate errors.